# Printing is not centered and scanner does not work

Tags: printing, scanner

I have a Canon MFC642 have the drivers installed from the Canon website. Pages are printed off-center. I tested to make sure it wasn't a hardware issue by printing from different sources and they are all fine.

Also the scanner does not work. I imagine there are no supported Linux drivers.

Please how can I troubleshoot these issues?

Device URI: `ipp://printer.local:631/ipp/print`

I'm running:

```
4.15.0-118-generic
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

EDIT: Output from airscan

```
$ scanimage -L
device `airscan:e0:Canon MF642C/643C/644C (a5:a7:ce)' is a eSCL Canon MF642C/643C/644C (a5:a7:ce) eSCL network scanner

$ airscan-discover 
[devices]
  Canon MF642C/643C/644C (a5:a7:ce) = http://192.168.0.10:80/eSCL/, eSCL
  Canon MF642C/643C/644C (a5:a7:ce) = http://192.168.0.10/active/msu/scan, WSD
```

Comment: please add the settings used to print. could it be set to align left or have a larger printing border on one side. This might be an issue with default setting as it sometimes makes sense to leave some space for punching holes on the left.

Comment: All defaults. There are no settings for page offset

Comment: What "sources" are you referring to in "printing from different sources and they are all fine"?  When are they not fine?

Comment: I can give you a solution to the scanning issue but it is dependent on the device being connected by wireless. Is it? If not - could it be?

Comment: @xiota By sources I meant printing from Android, Windows, USB. These all print fine. When printing from Xubuntu, it is messed up

Comment: @brian_p I can connect either wireless or by wire

Comment: @drum Android  uses driverless printing. Your Xbuntu can also do this. Provide what `driverless` gives you and a solution will be formulated.

Comment: `driverless` gives me the URI `ipp://printer.local:631/ipp/print`

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution for scanning over a wireless connection on Ubuntu 18.04. It also should work with wireless and USB connections on Ubuntu 20.04.

Download and install [sane-airscan](https://github.com/alexpevzner/sane-airscan)

The file needed is [here](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/pzz/xUbuntu_18.04/amd64/)

sane-airscan is part of Debian unstable and Ubuntu Groovy and regarded as a very competent driverless scanning utility for modern scanners.

I would appreciate knowing if you can now scan and having the outputs of `scanimage -L` and `airscan-discover`.

Comment: Oh wow. This did the trick for the scanner! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @drum Glad to have helped. The info I requested would be good to have because it will benefit other users.

Answer (score 0):

This a solution for printing that does not use the Canon drivers. Set up a print queue with

```
lpadmin -p PRINTER_NAME -v URI -E -m everywhere
```

PRINTER_NAME can be anything you choose but URI has to be **ipp://printer.local:631/ipp/print**.

I would test first with

```
lp -d PRINTER_NAME /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

and move on to a file that has previously printed off-center.

Comment: Why don't you combine your answers with separate sections for printing and scanning?